# Maintaining database shared between multiple solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 2 solutions. An ASP.NET MVC solution and a Console Application solution. They both share the same database.
The console app is basically a cron job that runs every now and then doing stuff with the data in the database. The ASP.NET MVC is just a frontend.

That all well and dandy. However the issue arise when I want to make changes to the database, then I have to make my changes in one solution and update the database (EF Migrations) then go to the other solution and somehow update the code there as well so I don't get the DbContext out of date exception.

That's bound to be forgotten at some point. :(

The ideal solution (I think) would be if ASP.NET MVC had build in cron job support. Much like the AzureJob thing. But my solution is hosted on an IIS server, so that's not an option.

What are my options here? I'm looking for the most maintainable solution possible.

Comment: You mean changes in database structure or data?

Comment: @x2. Changes in structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write an assembly, which do nothing else than the data-access. These assembly are often called DataAccessLayer (DAL). If you have one data access layer, you can use it in both applications. This will make your development process much smarter and you get rid of the problem, that one project use the obsolet data structure.

**EDIT**

To deploy the assembly would write a batch-file which do all the work.

A more advanced solution would be to set up your own Nuget-Server or something like this. But for this case it is not necessary.

Comment: Would you then manually copy the assembly to other solution or is there a smarter way?